# Configure repository to use my RSA key

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a public key file associated with my github account. On my computer, all git repositories use that file when I use `git push`. One repository, however, is broken and I cannot push anything. The error I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Since the other repositories work, there must be some problem with using the correct RSA file. How do I set the repository to use correctly the `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` when connecting to GitHub? This is my list of "remotes":

```
github  https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECT-NAME.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECT-NAME.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/PROJECT-NAME.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/PROJECT-NAME.git (push)
```

When pushing using `origin`, I need to use the RSA file.

Comment: What does the list of remotes look like for the working repos? Do you have the same access rights for all repos?

Comment: @HaraldNordgren Yes. The only difference is that this particular repo was ALSO connected to our university git server. But those remotes were already removed.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `git config -l` and your environment variables for any clue which could explain this.

With a recent enough (GIt 2.10+), you also can set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to:

```
ssh -v
```

That will allow to debug any git command using ssh: you will see exactly what ssh does for that repo that is might do differently for other repos.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll see what I can find out.